# Is there any way to combine \cs_if_exist_use and \exp_args?

Tags: expl3

In my package, there are quite a lot language-related commands, that are named as `..._ \languagename :n`. In some cases, it requires the commands to receive the value of the argument, and for this the `:V` or `:x` form shall be needed.

Usually I can do `\exp_args:NV` or `\exp_args:Nx`, but here since there is a dynamical part `\languagename` in the command name, I have to use something like `\cs_if_exist_use:cTF` for using the command, and it is not clear to me if I can still `\exp_args` in this case. Is there some way to use `\exp_args` alongside with the `:c` specifier?

Comment: `:c` will expand token lists inside the argument, so `\cs_if_exist_use:cTF { __jinwen_ \language :n }` will work as long as `\language` is expandable.

Comment: @Skillmon Sorry, I didn't state the question clear. It is the command itself that requires to receive the value of the argument, for example using as `\exp_args:Nx \..._english:n { the value of this token list is needed }`. But now the command is called using `:c`, so `\exp_args:Nx` will not be applied to the command but rather to `\cs_if_exist_use`, and this is what troubles me.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to make sure you define variants of your commands then check for (e.g.) `{ __jinwen_ \language :x }`.

Comment: Note that in general you should only be using an explicit `\exp_args:N...` for strictly one-off uses of a variant: in general, prefer generating a variant and then using that.

Comment: your question is not very clear. your command should have a base definition taking N or n argument then declare c or x variant commands as required, you should only rarely need to use `\exp_args` explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you're referring to `crefthe.sty`. Let's see your usages of `\exp_args:...`

###### First example

```
            \exp_args:Nx \str_case:nn \l__crefthe_prep_mode_tl
              {
                { - } { \tl_gset:Nn \g__crefthe_prep_once_tl { #4 } }
                { + } { \tl_gset:Nn \g__crefthe_prep_each_tl  { #4 } }
              }
```

is wrong and should be `\str_case:Vn \l__crefthe_prep_mode_tl`

###### Second example

```
            \exp_args:Nnx \str_case_e:nnF { #1~\text_lowercase:n{ #2 } }
              {
                \tl_use:c { crefthe_contraction_rule_ \languagename _tl }
              }
              { #1~\text_lowercase:n{ #2 } }
```

First of all, `\text_lowercase:n` should actually be `\str_foldcase:n`and you rather want

```
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_case_e:nn { nv } { p, T, F, TF }
```

to have `\str_case_e:nvF` available so you can do

```
            \str_case_e:nvF { #1~\str_foldcase:n{ #2 } }
              { g_crefthe_contraction_rule_ \languagename _tl }
              { #1~\str_foldcase:n{ #2 } }
```

The `v` argument type stands to `V` as `c` stands to `N`: the variable name will be constructed from the csname and then `V` would be applied to it.

Note that I have changed the variable name to have a `g_` prefix; indeed you do

```
\tl_gset:Nn \crefthe_contraction_rule_french_tl
  {
    { à~le }      { au }
    { à~les }     { aux }
    { de~le }     { du }
    { de~les }    { des }
    { À~le }      { Au }
    { À~les }     { Aux }
    { De~le }     { Du }
    { De~les }    { Des }
  }
```

but it should be

```
\tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_contraction_rule_french_tl
  {
    { à~le }      { au }
    { à~les }     { aux }
    { de~le }     { du }
    { de~les }    { des }
    { À~le }      { Au }
    { À~les }     { Aux }
    { De~le }     { Du }
    { De~les }    { Des }
  }
```

and similarly for the other variables.

Comment: Thank you for this! Actually I’m referring to my package `ProjLib` which is being rewritten, but of course its code shares the same problems with `crefthe`. I’ll try my best to correct my syntax.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but I've encountered some problems. As my test document shows, 1) changing `\exp_args:Nx \str_case:nn` to `\str_case:Vn` breaks the functionality, probably because the `\str_case_e:nn { \languagename }` inside `\l__crefthe_prep_mode_tl`? 2) Changing `\text_lowercase:n` to `\str_foldcase:n` also breaks the functionality, and even if I extend it to use `\str_foldcase:x` the article contraction still won't work correctly. (By the way, may I assume `\text_lowercase:n` shall always expand its argument, or is it better to create a `:x` variant and use this to be certain?)

Comment: @Jinwen `\text_lowercase:n` is for *printing text*, not for programmatical jobs.